# formatting setw() function equivalent to 1 \t tab

Tags: c++

I would like to know the value I'm going to input that is equivalent to one tab.
For example setw(?) == \t. I just want to know the equivalent of it.

Comment: tl;dr of the dupe: it depends

Comment: Tabs are always 8 spaces.  Except when they are 2, 3 or 4.  Or something else.

Comment: so  you guys mean that if i put setw(8) it equates to 1 tab?

Comment: no, i meant: It depends. A tab is a tab. It advances to the next tab stop and they are often 8 spaces apart, but it can be any other value

Comment: my question has not been answered yet, i'm referring to the setw() function. You gotta put numbers inside "()", so how many numbers should I enter to represent a tab?

Comment: the answer is: There is no real equivalent. Did you read the duplicate? It usually is 8 spaces but not always. It depends...

Comment: `setw` uses tabs if you've done `setfill('\t')`.  It will act as if tabs are set to 1 space.